# Can ST L3GD20 Gyro's Low pass filter be disabled?

Tags: gyro, gyroscope, st

I am fairly new to hardware and datasheets and looking at the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00036465.pdf) of ST's L3GD20 Gyro I know that the high pass filter's frequency can be chosen, but it can also be disabled at all. I cannot understand whether the embedded low pass filter can be disabled too?

Comment: It doesn't seem the low-pass can be disabled. Looks like it's hard-wired in an analog fashion (See _Block Diagram_ at page 7.) I think they had to have a very good reason to include it.

Comment: Does that mean, that the Gyro is unusable for frequencies higher than 100Hz? Its max ODR is 760Hz. Following Nyquist's rule the max freq should be 380Hz, meaning a 200Hz should also be usable.

Answer (score 1):

The HPF does look like it should be bypassable. Take a look at the diagram below: -

[image]

I've circled the multiplexer in red - this multiplexer chooses whether to use the HPF or not use it. The clue is the phrase HPen (I take this as HP enable): -

[image]

The low pass filter (LPF2) can also be bypassed by setting OUT_SEL=01

Comment: The question was for the low pass filter, not the high pass, but the same diagram answers it :)

Comment: OK yes, I see the LP disable function. Use OUT_SEL = 01. What confused me was the "too" at the end of your question but your English is better than my Bulgarian!